# Incomplete response received from application with API request to OpenAI

Tags: flask, cpanel, openai-api

I'm currently running a flask app in python using the cPanel. The web app is returning the error:

> Incomplete response received from application

I believe this occurs when running an API request to OpenAI. I narrowed it down to this section using try/exception blocks in my code. I'm guessing this is due to the server timeout issue? Could this be because I'm in "Starter Premium Hosting"? It's hard to tell why.  Any insights you can give would be great. My code runs good locally, but not when deployed. I tried setting the timeouts in the PHP version section of cPanel. The error occurs fairly quickly after posting my form, which makes an API call. I confirmed the API key is reaching the function.

```
def generate_openai_response(prompt, engine, openai_key):
    if openai_key:
        try:
            client = OpenAI(api_key=openai_key)
            completion = client.chat.completions.create(
                model=engine,
                messages=[
                    {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."},
                    {"role": "user", "content": prompt}
                ]
            )
            return completion.choices[0].message
        except Exception as e:
            app.logger.error(f"OpenAI Error: {str(e)}")
            return "Error in generating response from OpenAI"+openai_key
    else:
        return "OpenAI API key not set."
```

Tried changing various cPanel settings, different ways to call the OpenAI API, WSGI stuff, gunicorn etc.

Comment: I found the solution, the web server was blocking openais ip address. If you have similar problems the solution may be to unblock the ip address.  Thanks